# Como executar método clicando num button type

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-5, asp

Ola,
Estou a fazer uma aplicação que pode fazer recover da password do utilizador e mandar a password para o email da team de suport. 
Para isso tenho uma página `.aspx` que tem codigo html e tenho na classe `recoverpassword` um método que lhe chamei `sendemail()` para enviar os mails. O que eu quero é quando se clicar nesse button seja executado o método sendemail que esta dentro da classe da página. O método `sendemail()` tem o código igual a muitos exemplos da net.

**Código HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Cegos Analytics | Lockscreen</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="hold-transition lockscreen">
<!-- Automatic element centering -->
<div class="lockscreen-wrapper">
  <div class="lockscreen-logo">
   <img src="/Images/^082594892CD6A1E2D2CF4B7361463D84FEF2B4C6FEBD2707B5^pimgpsh_fullsize_distr.png" alt="Cegos Logo">
  </div>
    <br />
  <!-- User name -->
  <div class="lockscreen-name"></div>

  <!-- START LOCK SCREEN ITEM -->
  <div class="lockscreen-item">
    <!-- lockscreen image -->
    <div class="lockscreen-image">
      <img src="/Images/locked.jpg" alt="Locked Screen">
    </div>
    <!-- /.lockscreen-image -->

    <!-- START LOCK SCREEN ITEM -->
  <div class="lockscreen-item">
    <!-- lockscreen image -->
    <div class="lockscreen-image">
      <img src="/Images/locked.jpg" alt="Locked Screen">
    </div>
    <!-- /.lockscreen-image -->
</div>

    <!-- lockscreen credentials (contains the form) -->
    <form class="lockscreen-credentials" action="RecoverPassword.aspx" method="post">
      <div class="input-group">
         <input id='user' type="Text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">    
    <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button id='enviar' type="submit" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right text-muted"></i></button>
         </div>

     </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!-- /.lockscreen credentials -->

  </div>
  <!-- /.lockscreen-item -->
  <div class="help-block text-center">
    Enter your username to retrieve your session
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <a href="../Default.aspx">Or sign in as a different user</a>
  </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  <%--  <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />--%>
    <br />
  <div class="lockscreen-footer text-center">
        <p style="height: 42px" align="center">&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() %> - <strong>Cegos Elearning Reports</strong>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.center -->

<!-- jQuery 2.2.0 -->
<script src="../../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#enviar").click(function () {
               @SendEmail();//Insira aqui o código para chamar o sender email.
    });
</script>



            </form>

            </body>

</html>
```

**página EnviarEmail.aspx.cs** :

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;


namespace Email
{
    public partial class Enviaremail : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void SendEmail()
        {

            SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient();
            cliente.Host = "smtp.sapo.pt";
            cliente.EnableSsl = true;
            cliente.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("suportcegos@sapo.pt", "cegoc123456");

            MailMessage mensagem = new MailMessage();
            mensagem.Sender = new MailAddress("suportcegos@sapo.pt");
            mensagem.From = new MailAddress("suportcegos@sapo.pt");
            mensagem.To.Add(new MailAddress("nsoares@cegoc.pt"));
            mensagem.Subject = "Pedido de suporte Plataforma Cegos Analytics";
            mensagem.Body = "Recebeu um pedido de suporte da  Plataforma Cegos Analytics para recuperação de passwor referente ao utilizador:";
            mensagem.IsBodyHtml = false;
            mensagem.Priority = MailPriority.High;

            cliente.Send(mensagem);

        }
    }
}
```

E no `EnviarEmail` com a ajuda do @Duque e @Leonardo Coelho tenho isso:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <%--<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />--%>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="campo" /> <button type="button" class="botao">Recuperar senha</button>

    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var sendEmail = function () {

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',

            url: 'http://localhost:5562/Enviaremail.aspx',  //Aqui é a URL até o método onde está a instrução de enviar o e-mail

            dataType: 'html',

            success: function (data) {
                //Trate o retorno sem erros
            }, error: function (request, status, error) {
                //Trate os erros
            }

        });

    }

    $("#enviar").click(function () {
        //Faz a chamada da função ajax
        sendEmail();
    });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

---

Que esta faltando para ainda não ter sucesso? Eu clico no botão e não faz nada nem submite nem nada. Me ajudem por favor

Podem-me ajudar a ver o que estou a fazer mal?
Obrigado.

Comment: Não está duplicada. editei a pergunta para me ajudarem. Coloquei mais informação. Não é duplicação

Comment: Nelson, apesar de ter código diferente, as perguntas parecem tratar exatamente do mesmo problema: enviar email ao clicar no botão. Eu li e reli e não vi distinção prática. Por isso também votei pra fechar como duplicada. Se vc não concorda, edite esta novamente pra tentar deixar ainda mais claro. Assim talvez ela seja reaberta.

Answer (score 0):

O melhor caminho é fazer uma chamada Ajax, para isso:

```
var sendEmail  =   function () {

    $.ajax({    

        type: 'POST',

        url: 'http://www.seusite.com.br/metodo',  //Aqui é a URL até o método onde está a instrução de enviar o e-mail

        dataType: 'html',

        success: function (data) {
           //Trate o retorno sem erros
        },error: function(request, status, error){
            //Trate os erros
        }

    });

}

$("#enviar").click(function () {
    //Faz a chamada da função ajax
    sendEmail();
});
```

> Mais detalhes sobre chamadas AJAX com JQuery: [Função Ajax JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Obrigado Duque. Mas onde coloco este código? o url é por exemplo localhost.//Report/Recoverpassword.aspx? Obrigado

Comment: Esse codigo ficará no mesmo lugar onde está o seu código JS da página.
Se a URL que você acessa para enviar o email é: localhost.//Report/Recoverpassword.aspx, então esse é o valor a ser setado no parametro URL.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o framework [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) você pode usar a propriedade [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) desta forma.

```js
$('.botao').on('click', function() {
 var campo = $('.campo');
 $.ajax({
  url: 'url_do_seu_metodo_php',
  method: 'post',
  data: campo.serialize(),
  success: function(resultado) { // Resultado da Consulta
   console.log(resultado); // Verifique o console
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="email" class="campo" /> <button type="button" class="botao">Recuperar senha</button>
```

Você está usando asp, este exemplo está em PHP, a diferença é só a forma como você irá capturar o post que foi enviado ao documento.

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: Solução duplicada não ?